# Kotlin: Formatting a print output to separate integers entered with a comma

Tags: kotlin

How do I separate my user input of integers with commas, for example I enter 78 69 25 13. And I want my output to be 78, 69, 25, 13.

```
fun main() {
    print("Enter your grades: ")
    while (true) {
        val studentGrades = readLine()
        println("Your grades are: ${"%,d".format(studentGrades)}")
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val studentGrades = readLine().orEmpty()
// ", " - default joinToString separator 
println("Your grades are: ${studentGrades.split(" ").joinToString()}")
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html

Answer (score 0):

You can split and join as IR42's answer. But I think doing a simple replacement as below will be a lighter option. The use of regex is optional but provides safety if you have multiple spaces between digits.

```
studentGrades.replace(Regex("\\s+"), ", ")
```